# How can I solve ELIFECYCLE npm Loopback error?

Tags: node.js, npm, loopbackjs

I've been trying to solve this error without success when running `Loopback`:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! backend@1.0.0 start: `node -r source-map-support/register .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-03-30T22_35_05_684Z-debug.log
```

I have tried to solve it, by verifying the cache, and updating the npm version, but I couldn't.

Pd: I'm using Linux (Ubuntu 19.10).

Comment: ELIFECYCLE usually means the script you are trying to run is exiting with non-zero status (unix interprets this as exit with errors). Try debug the source-map-support/register script instead of npm. There is probably no issues with npm

Comment: Thank you, @slebetman, I have another question. How can I debug the source-map-support/register script?